# Write results to Excel

Tags: python, excel, numpy, pandas, xlwt

I'm quite new to python programming. I'm trying to write results using python xlwt module to excel. The errors were **TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable.** I could not fix it. Could anyone kindly help me for this. I appreciate any help.

```
from math import *
import pylab as z;
from matplotlib import style
import numpy as np;
from xlwt import *
import xlwt


SMALL_FONT =("Verdana", 8)
style.use('ggplot')

def PriceMovements(S0, down, up, totalsteps, upsteps):
    S = S0*(pow(up, upsteps))*(pow(down, totalsteps-upsteps))
    return S

def binomial(d, u, p):
    g = np.random.binomial(1,p)

    if g == 1:
        return u
    else:
        return d
def write(self, r, c, label =""):
    self.row(r).write(c, label)

#Use the following numbers to console the setting for binomial graph

nodes = 8 #Nodes
S = 100.0 #Initial spot price
u = 1.1346 #Up factor
d = 0.8814 #Down factor
p = 0.7844 # Probability
r = 1.08 #1+Interest rate
n = 3 #Steps

numberofpaths = 2**nodes
valuelist = [] #Emptylist
z.figure(0) #Generating the figure
temp = S #Temporary variable

for i in range(0, numberofpaths, 1):
    valuelist =[]
    S = temp;
    for c in range(0, nodes + 1, 1):
        valuelist.append(S)
        S = S*binomial(d, u, p)
    z.plot(range(0, nodes + 1, 1), valuelist)
    for i in range(nodes):
        z.text(i+.2,valuelist[i]-25,'{:4.1f}'.format(valuelist[i]))

wb = xlwt.Workbook()
ws = wb.add_sheet('Sheet1')
for r, row in enumerate(valuelist):
    for c, col in enumerate(row):
        ws.write(r, 2+c, lable = col)


wb.save('exampleResult.xls')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC you need enumerate list `valuelist`, because `row` is value with `type` `float`:

```
print valuelist
[100.0, 113.46000000000001, 100.00364400000001, 113.46413448240001, 128.73640698373106,
 146.06432736374126, 165.72458582690084, 146.06964994783038, 165.73062483080835]

for r, row in enumerate(valuelist):
    print r
    print row
    ws.write(r, 2+r, label = row)

    0
    100.0
    1
    113.46
    2
    100.003644
    3
    113.464134482
    4
    128.736406984
    5
    146.064327364
    6
    165.724585827
    7
    146.069649948
    8
    165.730624831

wb.save('exampleResult.xls')
```

EDIT by comment:

I think you need create new `list` of `lists` filled by `valuelist` in each loop. Then you can create `DataFrame` and write it [`to_excel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html):

```
import pandas as pd
...

numberofpaths = 2**nodes
valuelist = [] #Emptylist
#add listofvaluelists 
listofvaluelists = []
z.figure(0) #Generating the figure
temp = S #Temporary variable

for i in range(0, numberofpaths, 1):
    valuelist =[]
    S = temp;
    for c in range(0, nodes + 1, 1):
        valuelist.append(S)
        S = S*binomial(d, u, p)
    z.plot(range(0, nodes + 1, 1), valuelist)
    #append listofvaluelists
    listofvaluelists.append(valuelist)
    for i in range(nodes):
        z.text(i+.2,valuelist[i]-25,'{:4.1f}'.format(valuelist[i]))

#print listofvaluelists
#create new DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(listofvaluelists)
print df
#write DataFrame to excel
df.to_excel('exampleResult.xls', sheet_name='Sheet1')
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Actually, I didn't get all results from python.

Comment: It passed only one result per each row. For example, row A = 100.00, row B = 113.46; row C = 100.00, row D = 113.46, and so on. I think that it didn't pass results into columns (it is supposed so). In fact, when we printed we obtained data series which I wanted to pass it all to excel.

Comment: @jezael thank you so very much for your help. It works.

Comment: Super. :) Glad can help you.